# Elasticsearch and Search UI with docker

Tags: docker, user-interface, elasticsearch, search

I'm novice with elasticsearch and Docker. I found a great utility to filter data to final users "Search UI": https://github.com/elastic/search-ui

I see that all services I need to manage my "ES" network are available with Docker, but Search UI not. My question is, how can I add Search UI to my docker compose file?

Here is my actual docker-compose file:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
      - 9301:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9202:9200
      - 9302:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.1
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9203:9200
      - 9303:9300
    networks:
      - elastic

  cerebro:
    image: lmenezes/cerebro:0.8.5
    container_name: cerebro-01
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    external_links:
      - es01:es01
      - es02:es02
      - es03:es03
    networks:
      - elastic

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.6.1
    container_name: kibana-01
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    environment:
      ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS: http://es01:9200
    networks:
      - elastic

  appsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/app-search/app-search:7.6.1
    container_name: appsearch-01
    environment:
      - "elasticsearch.host=http://es01:9200"
      - "allow_es_settings_modification=true"
      - "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation says that it is a library to develop a UI, not an actual UI